# ISPCONFIG Ubuntu 14.04 phpmyadmin 404 Not Found

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

After following this tutorial https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4, and successfully completed when i try to acces phpmyadmin from ispconfig i get 404 Not Found.

Does someone else encountered this problem ?